# Right use of "follow up" phrase

Tags: phrase-usage

I've read an article on something from my line of work and I would like to contact the journalist who wrote it and send him results of the research I've done which is closely related to what he wrote about.
I was thinking about sending him an email with the research but I'm not sure about the subject line.

> Can I write "Follow up on your article about x"?

Is this the right way to use "follow up" phrase?

Comment: "Is this correct" questions are off-topic.  However, you're using the phrase correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is grammatically correct, I give you a cut-off of a unit concerning this question from the LDOCE 5th edition:

> follow something ↔ up (phrasal verb)

- **1** to find out more information about something and take action if necessary

*The police take people’s statements and then follow them up.*

- **2** to do something in addition to what you have already done in order to make it more likely to succeed

> follow something ↔ up with

*If there is no response to your press release, follow it up with a phone call.*

*This experiment was quickly followed up by others using different forms of the drug.*